# Should I accept offers from universities in two different countries to account for any possible uncertainties in getting visas?

Tags: undergraduate, university, visa

I’ve received an offer letter for B.Sc Computer Science from San Francisco State University (CA, USA) and Wilfrid Laurier University (ON, Canada). After accepting the offer letter from SFSU, I also applied for a US visa. However, in case of uncertainties with the US visa, will it be favourable to also accept Wilfrid Laurier University’s offer letter and apply for a Canadian visa later?
(both the offer letters are for the Fall 2022 semester)

Comment: Favorable for whom? Do you expect visa issues? Have you discussed with the institutions?

Comment: @JonCuster I do not expect any issues, but there are always some uncertainties.

Comment: We cannot predict the outcome of your visa.  If you break your agreement with SFSU you loose your $100 deposit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepting two offers when you can in reality only accept one is a guaranteed way to burn bridges at at least one of the two places. I don't see an upside for you doing this.

I am not an expert on the US visa system so I do not know how likely you are to run into problems, so take my next sentence with a grain of salt. From what I understand talking to people I have worked with, if you have accepted an offer from an American university, you should be able to get the visa. I don't think you would get an offer if the university thought there was a large chance you could not get the visa. There should also be an international office at the university you can contact to get more information about this; you can always ask them how often visa applications from your country are rejected and for what reasons.

There is always an option to apply again next year to universities outside the US if the visa process does not work out.

Comment: It's undergraduate admissions.  There are no bridges to burn.

Comment: "if you have accepted an offer from an American university, you should be able to get the visa."  That's not plausible.  "I don't think you would get an offer if the university thought there was a large chance you could not get the visa."  The university does not know.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist can you please add a detailed answer?

Comment: @RehmatSinghGill For what it's worth I think the best advice you will get about the visa is by contacting the international office at the university that made you the offer and the department who made you the offer. Explain your situation and any specific details that might be relevant. I don't think anyone here on the internet can do a better job. My answer is just meant to be kind of generic, and assumes you are from a country where students regularly are admitted to this university and that you don't have any special circumstances. But -- do not accept two offers intending to turn down one.